# Weird system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I've been working with the following system of differential equations:

$x' = a_1 - b_1x - cx(x+y)$

$y' = a_2 - b_2y - cy(x+y)$

With initial conditions $x(0)=y(0)=0$.

I was wondering if anyone here by any chance happens to know an analytical solution to this, since I haven't been able to find one anywhere else.

Comment: It's a nonlinear system, so it's unlikely that you can find the solution explicitly. But you can draw the phase portrait and study the system qualitatively rather easily. (Depending on what information you need, that may or may not be enough, but you haven't told us the context, so it's impossible for us to say.)

Comment: Absolutely nothing can be said with so many parameters ! This system can be considered (for moderate values of parameter $c$) as a perturbation of a linear system. As Hans Lundmark as advised you, draw a [phase portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait) of the linear system (when $c=0$) for concrete values of the parameters, then understand how it evolves when $c$ is less and less small and identify critical combinations of parameters.

Comment: For $b_1=b_2$ you get a Riccati's differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Because of its non-linear nature (assuming that $c \neq 0$, because otherwise everything is trivial) it's not going to be particularly amenable to analytic solutions, but you *can* remove the dependence between $x$ and $y$ to apply univariate ODE solution methods (although in practice there are a bunch of different cases depending on the specific values of the coefficients). For example:

First, look at what happens when we separately add and subtract the DEs from each other:

$$\begin{eqnarray} x' + y' & = & a_1 + a_2 - b_1 x - b_2 y - cx (x + y) - cy (x + y) \\
& = & (a_1 + a_2) - \frac{b_1 + b_2}{2} (x + y) - \frac{b_1 - b_2}{2} (x - y) - c(x + y)^2 \\
x' - y' & = & a_1 - a_2 - b_1 x + b_2 y - cx (x + y) + cy (x + y) \\
& = & a_1 - a_2 - \frac{b_1 - b_2}{2} (x + y) - \frac{b_1 + b_2}{2} (x - y) - c(x - y)(x + y)
\end{eqnarray}$$

I'm now going to make the substitutions $u = x + y$, $v = x - y$, $A_1 = a_1 + a_2$, $A_2 = a_1 - a_2$, $B_1 = \frac{b_1 + b_2}{2}$, $B_2 = \frac{b_1 - b_2}{2}$, giving:

$$\begin{eqnarray} u' & = & A_1 - B_1 u - B_2 v - c u^2 \\
v' & = & A_2 - B_2 u - B_1 v - c uv
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now, if $B_2 = 0$ (i.e. if $b_1 = b_2$), then the first equation is just a separable first-order ODE in $u$ that you can solve for an implicit expression of $u$, and for certain values of the coefficients you might even be able to explicitly solve for $u$. From there, you can substitute the form of $u$ into the second equation to similarly solve for $v$.

Then if $B_2 \neq 0$, we can do some more manipulation:

$$\begin{eqnarray} B_2 v & = & A_1 - B_1 u - c u^2 - u' \\
B_2 v' & = & - B_1 u' - 2 c u u' - u'' \\
B_2 (A_2 - B_2 u - B_1 v - c uv) & = & - B_1 u' - 2 c u u' - u'' \\
B_2 v (B_1 + cu) & = & u'' + 2cuu' + B_1 u' - B_2^2 u + A_2 B_2 \\
(A_1 - B_1 u - c u^2 - u')(B_1 + cu) & = & u'' + 2cuu' + B_1 u' - B_2^2 u + A_2 B_2
\end{eqnarray}$$

and I'll let you try manipulating that last one, but eventually you'll get something like $u'' + p(u) u' + q(u) = 0$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials, which again is going to have a bunch of special cases that may be more or less approachable (e.g. if $p = 0$ or $q = 0$).

Comment: Good explanations.